# 2D Context Canvas Transparent Prototype items

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a canvas that creates squares and fades them in, however I am unable to get them to fade out.

I have created a pen here: https://codepen.io/randomsdfsdfsdf/pen/wyWZZr?editors=0010

On line 90, I am want to change the colour to transparent, so that the squares are fading out, rather than staying on the screen.
It is possible to change the colour of the squares with `this.color = 'pink';`, however when using anything with transparency it does not use a transparent colour. I'm not sure why transparent doesn't work, or if I am explicitly doing something wrong. I also tried using `this.globalAlpha = 0;` underneath that, and it still does not set the Alpha channel for that item.

Any help with this is appreciated.